# What is the fastest algorithm to compute rank of a rectangular matrix?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, time-complexity, linear-algebra, matrices

Given an $m \times n$ matrix (assuming $m \ge n$), what is the fastest algorithm to compute its rank and basis of the columns?

I am aware it can be solved through linear matroid intersection, which implies 
an $O(mn^{1.62})$ time deterministic algorithm and an $O(mn^{\omega-1})$ time randomized algorithm. Is there an $O(mn^{\omega-1})$ time deterministic algorithm that more directly reduce the problem (or Gaussian elimination) to matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can bring a $2n \times n$-matrix into echelon form in time 
$O(n^{\omega + \epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. See the book "Algebraic Complexity Theory" by Bürgisser, Clausen, Shokrollahi, Section 16.5.

Now you apply this procedure $m/n$ times to your $m \times n$-matrix.
This gives an algorithm with $O(mn^{\omega-1})$ arithmetic operations.

If you bring an $2n \times n$-matrix into echelon form, then it contains
a zero matrix of size $n \times n$ afterwards. You take the remaining $n \times n$-matrix,
add a new $n \times n$-block of your input matrix and bring this to echelon form and so on.

Comment: Do you mean splitting the $m$ rows into $m/n$ groups? How do you combine the $m/n$ results to give the rank? Consider two rows in echelon form from different groups that both have 1 in the first column, they may have rank 2 right?

Comment: Is there a lower bound for this? As in does the rank have any computational strength?

Answer (score 3):

We can compute the rank of a $m \times n$ matrix A in $\tilde{O}(\textrm{nnz}(A) + r^{\omega})$ time, where $\textrm{nnz}(A)$ is the number of non-zero entries in $A$ and $r$ is the rank of $A$. This follows from Theorem 1.1 in Cheung et. al. [[CKL'13]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2528404) and binary searching over $r$. This is faster than the $O(mn^{\omega-1})$ algorithm mentioned above.

Comment: I guess you mean "faster than the $O(mn^{\omega-1})$ algorithm" (I cannot edit the answer myself as the edit is too small)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The citation above is a paper by the OP so my answer is mostly for completeness.